# html image blob to base64

Tags: javascript, image, base64, blob

I've got some problems about to fileinputjs.The  images' src  are blob.But i want to use images' src to do something.So i use readAsDataURL to get base64.But there are any problems about it 。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#last").click(function(){
       var blob=document.querySelector(".file-preview-image").src;
       var reader = new FileReader(); //通过 FileReader 读取blob类型
   reader.onload = function(){
    this.result === dataURI; //base64编码
    }
    console.log(reader.readAsDataURL(blob));
})
     </script>
```

Then there are `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of misconception here.

- your variable `blob` is not a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob), but a string, the url of `.file-preview-image`.
  FileReader can't do anything from this string. (Or at least not what you want).
- in the `onload` callback of the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), you are just **checking** if the result is equal to an undefined variable `dataURI`. That won't do anything.
- you are trying to `console.log` the call to `readAsDataURL` which will be `undefined` since this method is asynchronous (you have to call `console.log` in the callback).

But since I guess that what you have is an [object url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) (`blob://`), then your solution is either to get the real Blob object and pass it to a `FileReader`, or to draw this image on a canvas, and then call its [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method to get a base64 encoded version.

If you can get the blob :

```js
var dataURI;

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(){
  // here you'll call what to do with the base64 string result
  dataURI = this.result;
  console.log(dataURI);
  };

reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

otherwise :

```js
var dataURI;

var img = document.querySelector(".file-preview-image");

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0,0);
dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
```

But note that for the later, you'll have to wait that your image actually has loaded before being able to draw it on the canvas.
Also, by default, it will convert your image to a png version. You can also pass `image/jpeg`as the first parameter of `toDataURL('image/jpeg')` if the original image is in JPEG format.
If the image is an svg, then there would be an other solution using the `<object>` element, but except if you really need it, I'll leave it for an other answer.

Comment: Seems I need your help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192069/how-can-i-solve-uncaught-referenceerror-blob-is-not-defined